# Round corners on stacked bars - MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, bar-chart

I need to create a chart with stacked bars and the bars need to be rounded. So far, I've succeeded in making the bars rounded, but if they're not stacked. If stacked, then each bar is rounded, which is something I don't need. I need the bar to be rounded regardless if it is stacked or not.

Here's how it should look [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB7A5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB7A5.png)

And here's how it looks at the moment [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzutk.png)

```
enter code here`  val trans: Transformer = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.axisDependency)
    mShadowPaint.color = dataSet.barShadowColor
    val phaseX = mAnimator.phaseX
    val phaseY = mAnimator.phaseY


    // initialize the buffer
    val buffer = mBarBuffers[index]
    buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY)
    buffer.setDataSet(index)
    buffer.setBarWidth(mChart.barData.barWidth)
    buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.axisDependency))
    buffer.feed(dataSet)
    trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer)

    // if multiple colors
    if (dataSet.colors.size > 1) {
        var j = 0
        while (j < buffer.size()) {
            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2])) {
                j += 4
                continue
            }
            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j])) break
            if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled) {
                if (mRadius > 0) c.drawRoundRect(
                    RectF(
                        buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                        buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()
                    ), mRadius, mRadius, mShadowPaint
                ) else c.drawRect(
                    buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                    buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    mViewPortHandler.contentBottom(), mShadowPaint
                )
            }

            // Set the color for the currently drawn value. If the index
            // is
            // out of bounds, reuse colors.
            mRenderPaint.color = dataSet.getColor(j / 4)
            if (mRadius > 0) c.drawRoundRect(
                RectF(
                    buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3]
                ), mRadius, mRadius, mRenderPaint
            ) else c.drawRect(
                buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint
            )
            j += 4
        }
    } else {
        mRenderPaint.color = dataSet.color
        var j = 0
        while (j < buffer.size()) {
            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2])) {
                j += 4
                continue
            }
            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j])) break
            if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled) {
                if (mRadius > 0) c.drawRoundRect(
                    RectF(
                        buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                        buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()
                    ), mRadius, mRadius, mShadowPaint
                ) else c.drawRect(
                    buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint
                )
            }
            if (mRadius > 0) {
                val corners = floatArrayOf(
                    mRadius, mRadius,   // Top left radius in px
                    mRadius, mRadius,   // Top right radius in px
                    0f, 0f,     // Bottom right radius in px
                    0f, 0f      // Bottom left radius in px
                )
                val path = Path()
                path.addRoundRect(RectF(
                    buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3]
                ), corners, Path.Direction.CW)
                c.drawPath(path, mRenderPaint)
            }
            else c.drawRect(
                buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint
            )
            j += 4
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you need to:

1. Find out the timing of rendering the top part of the bar, all other parts below it should be render as 'Rect', not 'RoundRect'.
2. Do NOT directly render the top part as 'RoundRect' because its height can be smaller than your radius.
3. Still render the top part as 'Rect' and after it's done, render two corners with chart background color but above the top part, like this:

   ```
            mRenderPaint.color = mChartBackgroundColor

            val tr = Path() // top right corner
            tr.moveTo(rect.right - radius, rect.top)
            tr.rLineTo(radius, 0f)
            tr.rLineTo(0f, radius)
            tr.rQuadTo(0f, -radius, -radius, -radius)
            tr.close()
            canvas.drawPath(tr, mRenderPaint)

            val tl = Path() // top left corner
            tl.moveTo(rect.left, rect.top + radius)
            tl.rLineTo(0f, -radius)
            tl.rLineTo(radius, 0f)
            tl.rQuadTo(-radius, 0f, -radius, radius)
            tl.close()
            canvas.drawPath(tl, mRenderPaint)
   ```